# Why I cannot open another file?

Tags: c

Im trying to make a matrix-vector multiplier program. Ive done with matrix reading, but when i add a new FILE* to the program it runs but nothing happens only i see black in the terminal. This code runs good for me, but if i add this: FILE* ptr2=fopen("abc.dat","rt");fclose(ptr2); it ruins it but i think its practically nothing, i think.thanks for the help guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j=0, c, d, z=9, sor, oszlop;
    char *temp, *buff;
    double *mtx, *tmp;

    FILE* ptr=fopen("test.dat", "rt");
    mtx=(double*)malloc(12*sizeof(*mtx));
    buff=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(*buff));

    for(;;) {
        c=fgetc(ptr);

        if(c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t') {
            continue;
        }

        i=0;
        if(isdigit(c) || c=='-' || c=='.') {
            buff[i]=c;
            do {
                d=fgetc(ptr);
                i=i+1;
                if(d==' ' || d=='\n' || d=='\0' || d=='\t') {
                    if(d=='\n') {
                        sor++;
                        break;
                    } else
                        break;
                }
                if(isdigit(d) || d=='-' || d=='.') {
                    buff[i]=d;
                }
            } while(d!=' ');
        }

        mtx[j]=atof(buff);
        j++;
        free(buff);
        if(j>z) {
            tmp=realloc(mtx,(2*j)*sizeof(double));
            if ( tmp != NULL ) {
                mtx=tmp;
            } else {
                printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
                return -1;
            }
        z=(2*j)-3;
        }
        buff=(char*)malloc(sizeof(*buff));

        if(c==EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }

    oszlop=(j-1)/sor;

    for (i = 0; i < sor; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < oszlop; j++) {
            printf("%lf ", mtx[oszlop * i + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    free(buff);
    free(mtx);

}
```

Comment: If you want people (or yourself in a few hours, days, months, ..) to read the code you write then you should try to make it *readable*. That means using good and descriptive names for the variables and functions you declare and using proper indentation as a minimum.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of test.dat and the expected output so we can run the code?

Comment: Side point: Don't cast the results of `malloc` in C.

Comment: These issues are sometimes caused by uninitialized variables. A quick check reveals that your `sor` (whatever it means) is not initialized.

Comment: Then the usual stuff: Don't cast the result of `malloc`, check the library functions for errors (`fopen`, `fgetc`, `malloc`, `realloc`, ..)

Comment: Also: Enable as many warnings as you can when compiling (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) and treat every single one of them as error unless you are 100% sure (that means you can provide a quote from the C standard justifying what you did).

Comment: I didn't get any warnings except 1 uninitialized variable, now that is good.  the code is pretty much unreadable though.

Comment: You don't know whether opening the file works because you don't check the return value from fopen.

Comment: I don't know what everyone else is on about. This is concise, elegant code. +1 for sor and oszlop. (That is an imaginary +1)

Comment: test.dat could be:
 -.78   (space, tabs maybe)    453  0/
7         14        48.34     /
(new line maybe) /
     29 -5000             1 /

result:
-0.78 453 0/
7 14 48.34/
29 -5000 1/

Comment: This insltruction `buff=(char*)malloc(sizeof(*buff));` allocates a buffer ONE char long! Is it what you actually want...?

Comment: Do you check the `ptr2` value, which came from `fopen()`, if it is not-null *before* you pass it to `fclose()`...?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite this:

```
if(j>z) {
        tmp=realloc(mtx,(2*j)*sizeof(double));
        if ( tmp != NULL ) {
            mtx=tmp;
        } else {
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
            return -1;
        }
```

to this, and now it works(at least what wanted to do):

```
 if(j>z) 
        {
        mtx=realloc(mtx,(2*j)*sizeof(double));
        if(mtx==NULL){
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
            return -1;}
        z=(2*j)-3;
        }
```

thx for the help everyone!from now i'll better pay attention that everybody can read it, not just me